# поиск на сайте по двум выбранным значениям селекта

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ss.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  
  <div class="container lol text-center text-white" style="background-color: lightblue">
      <div>
        <form name="a">
      <h2>value1</h2><br>
        <select id="c1" name="b" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        
</select>
</div>

<div>
      <br><br>
      <h2>value2</h2><br>
        <select id="c2" name="c" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        
</select>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input name="d"/>

<button>sub</button>

</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const

g = i => i.value = `${typeof i.dataset.b !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.b : ''}${typeof i.dataset.c !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.c : ''}`,

f = g => ev => {
  document.forms.a.d.dataset [ev.target.name] = ev.target.options [ev.target.selectedIndex].value
  g (document.forms.a.d)
}

[document.forms.a.b, document.forms.a.c].forEach (s => s.addEventListener ('change', f (g)))
</script>
</body>
```

Здравстуйте, нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку sub, открывалась страница, равная получившемуся значению в поле input, как можно заметить есть всего 100 вариантов значений, следовательно 100 возможных страниц, заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: ну так значение есть, просто редирект по клику на значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ss.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container lol text-center text-white" style="background-color: lightblue">
    <form name="a">  
    <div>
      <h2>value1</h2><br>
        <select id="c1" name="b" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>

</select>
</div>

<div>
      <br><br>
      <h2>value2</h2><br>
        <select id="c2" name="c" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>

</select>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input name="d" id="d"/>

    </form>
    <button onClick="go()">sub</button>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const

      g = i => i.value = `${typeof i.dataset.b !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.b : ''}${typeof i.dataset.c !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.c : ''}`,

f = g => ev => {
  document.forms.a.d.dataset [ev.target.name] = ev.target.options [ev.target.selectedIndex].value
  g (document.forms.a.d)
}

[document.forms.a.b, document.forms.a.c].forEach (s => s.addEventListener ('change', f (g)))

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
  s = document.getElementById('d').value;
  window.location = window.location+"?page="+s;
}
</script>
</html>
```